# Find the corresponding functions of the following power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

1. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{4n}}{n!}$
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)z^n$

My thoughts:

1. I think it'll look something like the exponential function but I'm not sure what exactly it would be.
2. the hint says to divide by $z^2$, and I got the power series to look like $$2z^2+6z^3+12z^4+20z^5+\cdots,$$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: In q2 your index should start at *n=1*

Answer (score 3):

If the general term for the first question is meant to be $\dfrac{z^{4n}}{n!}$, then rewrite the term as $\dfrac{(z^4)^n}{n!}$, and note that we are  looking at $e^{(z^4)}$.

For the second, consider the familiar $\sum_0^\infty z^n$, differentiate twice, and look at the result.

Answer (score 1):

And the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq0}n(n-1)z^n$ is the same as $z^2\sum\limits_{n\geq2}n(n-1)z^{n-2}$, which you should recognize.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the differentiation theorem for power series, it can be used to evaluated number 2.

Answer (score 0):

1) we know that $$e^x=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ let $x=z^4$ and you will get your first series.
2) you have the following$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)z^n=0+0+\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)z^{n-2}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)z^{n-2}$$ but we also have$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$$ if you differentiate twice you'll get the result.
 **Remark:** for part (2) the result is true if $|z|<1$.